# Unable to call method from class instance Android

Tags: android

I've created a class that updates a class variable. I'm creating a new instance of the class then trying to call a get method. But i'm getting a 'canno't resolve method error and I have no idea why.

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }
    int selectedDate;
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        selectedDate = day+month+year;
    }
    public int getSelectedDate() {
        return selectedDate;
    }

}
public void showDatePickerDialog(View view) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    int output = newFragment.getSelectedDate();
}
```

Comment: post the logcat error too.

Comment: For which method it thrown error? Show your logcat.

Comment: which method cannot be resolved?

Comment: Sorry, line:    `int output = newFragment.getSelectedDate();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error is here:

```
public void showDatePickerDialog(View view) {
   DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
   newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
   int output = newFragment.getSelectedDate();
}
```

your variable `newFragment` is a `DialogFragment`. So you must cast the variable or change the declaration like this:

```
DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
```

or

```
int output = ((DatePickerFragment)newFragment).getSelectedDate();
```

EDIT:
for get the selected date you must use Listener and not a sync method.
so you have to change in this way your code:

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
private MyListener listener;
public DatePickerFragment(MyListener listener){
   this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}
int selectedDate;
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    selectedDate = day+month+year;
    if(listener!=null){
        listener.theDateHasChanged(selectedDate);
    }
}
public int getSelectedDate() {
    return selectedDate;
}
```

And then your activity must implement the `MyListener` interface and implement `theDateHasChanged` and in the end you must instantiate your `fragment` from your `activity` so:

```
DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment(this);
```

Comment: ok so the code works. Thank you. What am I actually casting? My understanding was that the method would return an int which can then be passed into the variable.

Comment: Could you recommend a good resource? I'm not really clear on why I'm using a listener. Isn't the point of the method to handle the selected date?

Comment: when you show the fragment, the user need time to select the date.
To handle this async user operation you need to listen when the user has finished.
The view of fragment don't stop the execution of the java code so you read the `selectedDate` too soon and isn't set yet.
[here a good explain](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe that's because your class is static. In java, you cannot create an instance of a class that is defined as static. For a static class, you can directly call the methods by using 
 .();

```
DatePickerFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"datePicker");
```

Hope this helps. :)